# PHP で配列のキーだけ反対にしたい

Tags: php

## やりたいこと

配列の値を変更せずに、配列のキーだけ反対にしたいです。

## 例

```php
<?php
$first = [1,3,5];
print_r($first);
```

この結果は

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
)
```

となるのですが、その結果をキーだけ入れ替えて

```php
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [0] => 5
)
```

としたいと考えています。

## 調べたこと

「php 配列、キーだけ入れ替え」で調べたところ `array_reverse` という関数を見つけましたが、こちらはキーと値を全て入れ替えてしまうので今回自分がやりたいことではありませんでした。
この問題を解決するのに何かアドバイスがあればよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array_reverseはすべて入れ替えていますが、順番が違うだけなのでarray_reverseの結果を降順すればよいと思います。

keyを降順に並べるには[krsort](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.krsort.php)を使ってみてください

```
<?php
$first = [1,3,5];
print_r($first);

$reverse = array_reverse($first);
krsort($reverse);
print_r($reverse);
```

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じでしょうか？

```
$first = [1,3,5];
print_r($first);
$reverse = [];
$keys = array_keys($first);
$keys = array_reverse($keys);
$count = 0;
foreach($first as $value){
  $reverse[$keys[$count]] = $value;
  $count++;
}
print_r($reverse);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
)
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [0] => 5
)
```

キーだけの配列にして、その配列の順番を逆にして、それから元の値を入れます。

このやり方だと、連想配列でも大丈夫です。連想配列じゃない場合はkeitaro_soの答えの方が短くていいと思います。

つまり、こちらのやり方だとこういう配列でも平気です

```
Array
(
    [orange] => 1
    [apple] => 3
    [pear] => 5
)
Array
(
    [pear] => 1
    [apple] => 3
    [orange] => 5
)
```